# how to keep docker images if pulling newer image

Tags: docker

I'm using some docker images, which I have pulled from a registry:

```
docker pull registry.example.com/project/backend:latest
docker pull registry.example.com/project/frontend:latest
```

Now there is a new version on the server registry. If I do a new pull, I will overwrite the current images. But I need to keep the current working images in case I do get some problems with the newest `latest` images.

So, how do I create a kind of backup of my running `backend:latest` and `frontend:latest`? After that I can pull the latest `latest` image and in case I need to, I can use the old working images...

Comment: on the registry server there is only the latest tag. No version tags. Do I have to create them on my server by myself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To keep the current image on your local environment you can use docker tag

docker tag SOURCE_IMAGE[:TAG] TARGET_IMAGE[:TAG]

For example:

docker tag registry.example.com/project/backend:latest registry.example.com/project/backend:backup

Then when you pull the latest, the registry.example.com/project/backend:backup still existing

Answer (score 0):

Pulling an image never deletes an existing image. However, if you have an image with the same name, the old image will become unnamed, and you'll have to refer to it by its image ID.

You've now seen the downside to using `:latest` tags. This is why it is better to reference an image by a specific version tag that the maintainer won't re-push.

Comment: I am not the maintainer, so I have to use as it is. Would it be an option to create an own version tag on my running images?

Answer (score 0):

First, you shouldn't be using `latest` in production environments. Rather define a [tag](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/tag/) you confirmed working.

And instead of executing stuff in an image to set it up, you should write a [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) and make the installation repeatable and create your local image. That's actually one of the main reasons why docker is used.